# Cannot sign in to one website with any browser

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Windows 7 Professional install on a newish laptop that is unable to sign into one particular website. I can navigate to the website ok, enter the user-id and password (which works fine on other machines with the same setup) but when I press enter the fields go blank with no error message. I've tried IE11, Chrome & Firefox, disabling the firewall and AV software, swapping between the wireless adapter and the ethernet adapter, running the Microsoft fix for the hosts file, flushing dns, changing machine name, creating another user account on the machine, resetting IE to default settings, putting the website into a trusted zone, running Ccleaner to clean out cookies and temp data and quite frankly I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

I've enabled event logging in IE through a registry setting but nothing is logged.

The website can be signed into on other machines with Win 7 and Win 8 running IE or Chrome with no special setup and the same userid and password so it appears machine specific but what it is beats me. My next idea is to swap the hard drive into another identical laptop to see what happens....

Any ideas considered !

Comment: Very puzzling. I have a few suggestions: (1) try a browser with all add-ins disabled, eg `firefox -safe-mode`; (2) try your laptop on a different network (an alternative WiFi ot mobile hot-spot); (3) check if your router has a black-list (eg under firewall filter rules); or (4) if none of these suggest a reason for the problem, then you will need to use something like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to compare the communications on a working and failing system.